# excel vba: range xldown always copies at least 3 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some crazy problem with xldown.

I want it to copy a range that will vary (could have 0 entries, 1 entry or 10 entries. So I am referencing the starting location with Find and RngA.offset(1,4) and I want the range to go until it finds an empty cell. This seems to work if there are at least 3 rows of data (e.g., if there are 4 and then a blank, it will copy only the 4), but if there are 3 or less it copies all 3 (e.g., if there is data in row 1 and 3, but not in row 2, it should copy only row 1, because row 2 is blank. However it copies 1-3, with the blank in row 2). I hope that makes sense. Can anyone help?

```
    Sub SubmitData()
    Dim RngA As Range
     With Sheets("Review").Range("A:A")
        Set RngA = .Find(what:="TOR Design Checklist", lookat:=xlWhole)
        Range(RngA.Offset(1, 4), RngA.Offset(1, 4).End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Field_Phase 1").Range("H7")
     End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are the blanks the results of formulas? Or are the cells truly blank?

Comment: They are truly blanks, I have checked to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Following your exemple, the "select" is already at the last row before you call the `xldown`.

Just add an `if` statement before it to handle this unique case.

```
if {Range under your selected range} = "" then
    ' Only copy the 1 range
else
    ' Do as usual
End if
```

### Edit 1

Fitting on your question :

I think it should work. Comment if it doesn't.

```
Sub SubmitData()
Dim RngA As Range
With Sheets("Review").Range("A:A")
    Set RngA = .Find(what:="TOR Design Checklist", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If RngA.offset(2,4).value = "" then
        ' Only copy the 1 range
        Range(RngA.Offset(1, 4),RngA.Offset(1, 4)).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Field_Phase 1").Range("H7")
    else
        ' Do as usual
        Range(RngA.Offset(1, 4), RngA.Offset(1, 4).End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Field_Phase 1").Range("H7")
    End if
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure I understand. I am new to vba.

Comment: If the range starts at RngA.offset(1,4) why would it automatically fill 3 rows? - for example, if Rng.offset (2,4) is blank, it should only copy (1,4) right?

Comment: Onto your first comment : It is just an `if` statement that verifies that the second cell is **not** empty. This way, it handles the exception. Onto your second comment : No, because you have the `.End(xlDown)`. This command implies that, **at minimum**, it will grab one cell below, until **another** empty cell is found. Let me edit my answer accordingly.